# PHP: How do I fix this type hinting error?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, type-hinting

```php
function foo(int $one, int $two, int &$output): void
{
    $output = $one + $two;
}
foo(1, 2, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Produces this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to foo() must be of the type int, null given

Is there some way to avoid this without pre-setting `$result` to a value of the expected type, etc.?

Comment: Why set a type hint for `$output` at all?

Comment: For one, I'm in the habit of fully type hinting everything because I use static analysis tools like Psalm and PHPStan.  They will complain about the lack of type hint unless I code in exceptions via annotations/comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php#example-145)

> #### Typed pass-by-reference Parameters
>
> Declared types of reference parameters are *checked on function entry, but not when the function returns*, so after the function had returned, the argument's type may have changed.

Given you are immediately assigning a new value to `$output`, its type declaration is irrelevant. Either omit the type declaration or mark it *nullable*

```php
function foo(int $one, int $two, ?int &$output): void
{
    $output = $one + $two;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/j91DG

---

Of course, this type of pattern is convoluted and makes no sense over something as simple as

```php
function foo(int $one, int $two): int
{
    return $one + $two;
}
```

Comment: My real code is much more complex, and it actually makes sense to return via reference params, instead return value.  ;-)

Comment: Personal opinion but I feel it's rarely ever appropriate to return via reference / out parameters

Comment: I agree.  It's kind of an ugly work around to manage extending a library I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

You can with PHP 8 using Union Types:

```
function foo(int $one, int $two, int|null &$output): void
{
    $output = $one + $two;
}
foo(1, 2, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: If you're unioning with `null`, wouldn't it make more sense to use `?int`

Comment: @Phil, same thing different flavor imo

Comment: You could do `?int`, mentioned in the other answer, as far back as PHP 7.1